# Assistance Required on query DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm getting error
 **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { -dataTables.bootstrap.min.css:1"**

as a beginner, I did my best but it can't find out a solution for this.and the response of  servlet  is Json Data 
that's in the following format

```
{
   "TransferMoneyHistory":[
      {
         "amount":1000,
         "transactionDate":{
            "date":1,
            "hours":5,
            "seconds":0,
            "month":0,
            "timezoneOffset":-330,
            "year":70,
            "minutes":30,
            "time":2,
            "day":4
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I need  to display column index as "Amount " and "Transaction "
thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DepositDataTable").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "DepositHistory",
            "type": "Post",
            "success": function (jsonResponse) {
                console.log(jsonResponse)
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"jsonData": "Amount"},
            {"jsonData": "TransactionDate"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your html loading dataTables.bootstrap.min.css in a <script> tag instead of a <link> tag?

Comment: Yes, I made change it's  working Now but there is another one problem it not getting reflect on Html page.I think the problem is in column naming .could you help me?        thanks, Clayton,

Comment: `"success"` handlers in dataTables AJAX is "illegal", use `dataSrc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To use the jQuery DataTable, I suggest you to take a look on https://datatables.net/reference/ first.
In your case, to show the data correctly:
1. The Json response should look like this

```
{
  "recordsFiltered" : 1,
  "data" : [ {
     "amount":1000,
     "transactionDate":{
        "date":1,
        "hours":5,
        "seconds":0,
        "month":0,
        "timezoneOffset":-330,
        "year":70,
        "minutes":30,
        "time":2,
        "day":4
     }
  } ],
  "draw" : 2,
  "recordsTotal" : 1
}
```

2.By reference to https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns , the columns should be set as

```
"columns": [
        {
         // title of the column
         "title":"Amount",
         // the property of data in json response to show
         "data": "amount"
        },
        {
         "title":"TransactionDate",
         "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
           // need further handle for nested property,
           // refer to 
           https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render
         }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You need a `"data":"TransactionDate"` as well.